# Distribution of IEEE 754 single precision floating point over number line

Tags: floating-point, number-formats

> "*What is the maximum and minimum difference between two successive
>   real numbers representable in IEEE 754 Single Precision and Double
>   Precision Floating Point Representations respectively?*"

In order to answer this question, I am unable to visualise how Floating Points are spread over the real number line, assuming the precision of real numbers is same as that of IEEE 754 single precision & double precision respectively.
So I am looking for graphs of the following two functions based on IEEE 754 single precision representations.
$f\left ( x \right ) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
 0 & ,\text{if x can't be represented in IEEE 754 single precision.}  \\ 
 1 & ,\text{if x can be represented in IEEE 754 single precision.} 
\end{matrix}\right.$
$f\left ( n \right ) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
d, & \text{where d is the diffrence between n-th and (n-1)th floating points representable in IEEE 754 single precision. }\\ 
0, & \text{if n-th or (n-1)th floating point number does  not exists in IEEE 754 single precision representations.}
\end{matrix}\right.$
Considering only normalised values and zero.
and not considering Infinities, NaN and denormalised numbers.

Could anybody please help me out with these graphs so that I can understand floating points properly.

Comment: I don't think this is a helpful approach. The required quantities follow from the way the format is set up in an arithmetic way. That said, just take a shorter floating-point format -- $k$ bits so that your machine and plotting software can handle $2^k$ data points -- and *draw them all*.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that a (not denormalized) floating point number is stored as
$2^x \times 1.m_0 \ldots m_{k-1}$ (in binary),
where $x$ is the exponent and $m_0 \ldots m_{k-1}$ is the mantissa of length $k$. Two successive numbers with this exponent differ by $2^{x-k}$, since this minimal difference is $2^x \times 0.0\ldots01$, with $k-1$ zeroes after the dot. The minimal and maximal differences (among not denormalized numbers) are attained for the minimal and maximal $x$.

Comment: Note that the difference between two consecutive denormalised numbers is the same as the difference between two consecutive normalised numbers with the smallest possible exponent (e.g. the exp field =1).